# Inline attachments issue

Tags: java, outlook, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to send an email with java that has inline images.
The problem is that from the email preview Outlook shows me that the mail has attachment as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGc0X.jpg)

I add the attach to the email like this:

```
private void addFilesToEmailSMTP2(MimeMessage msg) throws MessagingException {

        MimeMultipart multipart = new MimeMultipart("related");

        MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        messageBodyPart.setContent(testo, "text/html");

        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

        for (Entry<String, String> a : attach.entrySet()) {//attach is pre populated with key: content-id, value: base64 encoded image

            messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

            try {
                byte[] byteArray = Base64.getDecoder().decode(a.getValue());

                File tempFile = File.createTempFile("tmpFile", null);

                try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);) {
                    fos.write(byteArray);
                }

                DataSource fds = new FileDataSource(tempFile);

                messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fds));
                messageBodyPart.setContentID(a.getKey());
                messageBodyPart.setDisposition(MimeBodyPart.INLINE);
                log.info("Adding attach {}", a.getKey());

                multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

            } catch (MessagingException | IOException e) {
                log.error(threadName + " Attachment " + a.getKey() + " threw error: " + e.getMessage(), e);
            }
        }


        msg.setContent(multipart);

    }
```

The email result ok, with the attach hidden and the images in the body, but outlook keep showing me the email with [attach](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGc0X.jpg)

Comment: Outlook is probably assuming that any multipart message has attachments.  You can try sending the images as inline data in the html, as described in the [JavaMail FAQ](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#sendmpr).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll try that. The wierd thing is that I was using Magnolia cms email library and that wont happen.. Idk on which library Magnolia is based on, but I think is on Java Mail.

Comment: Compare the MIME content of the message they're generating to see what's different.